# Wordpress 3.0 and maintenance mode - A Problem

Tags: wordpress, maintenance-mode

For some reason it seems that WP3.0 is bugged with everything relate to *maintenance-mode*.

The 2 maintenance-mode plugins (*maintenance-mode* & *wp-maintenance-mode*) cause the following problems:

1. **wp-maintenance-mode** doesn't allow u login as an admin. He just blocks you at the wp-login page.
2. **wp-maintenance-mode** even doesnt influence a thing.

The same thing happend to me when I tried to [write it by myself using this tutorial](http://sivel.net/2009/10/wordpress-maintenance-mode-without-a-plugin-part-3/).

This line worked perfect and showed the built-in maintenance screen, but when I tried to add the condition for `is_user_logged_in()`, the mode stops working, letting you see the cliend & back end, when u r logged in or logged out.

What can I do?
Thanks for all the answerers.

Comment: Is this a programming issue? If not then it's likely to get closed as "off topic".

Comment: It might be cause it might demand an API usage of WP.
And can't I publish question regarding WP here?

thanks, Shlomi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `is_user_logged_in()` function the tutorial provides is pretty terrible, and it's why you're getting false positives for being 'logged in'.

Instead, load the pluggable file that contains the default WordPress `is_user_logged_in()` function;

```
require_once (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');
if ( ! stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin') && ! stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-login.php') && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    $upgrading = time();
else
    $upgrading = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you man for your answer.
I've loaded the pluggable file and I got this error- "Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_ssl()". I read and it seems like I have to dig into the php definitions of the server.
I'm giving up and will upload everything so fast, that my users won't sense the update :)

Comment: Just add this line before the others; `require_once (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/functions.php');`!